# Angular Karma Jasmine forEach@ Error

Tags: angularjs, foreach, jasmine, karma-jasmine, loadmodule

I'm trying to test an interceptor with Karma and Jasmine, but having unexpected errors. I was following this code: http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/20/testing-interceptor-headers-in-angularjs/

Code:

```
angular
    .module('xos.helpers',[
      'ngCookies',
      'xos.xos',
      'xos.hpcapi',
      'xos.xoslib',
      'bugSnag'
    ])
    .config(config);

function config($httpProvider, $resourceProvider) {
  console.log('xos.helpers config')
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('SetCSRFToken');

  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');

  // NOTE http://www.masnun.com/2013/09/18/django-rest-framework-angularjs-resource-trailing-slash-problem.html
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}
```

Test:

```
  'use strict';
    describe('The xos.helper module', function(){
      var SetCSRFToken, httpProviderObj;

      beforeEach(module('xos.helpers'));

      beforeEach(module(function(_$httpProvider_){
        httpProviderObj = _$httpProvider_;
      }));

      beforeEach(inject(function(_SetCSRFToken_){
        SetCSRFToken = _SetCSRFToken_;
      }));

      it('should exist', () => {
        expect(SetCSRFToken).toBeDefined();
      });

      it('should set SetCSRFToken interceptor', () => {
        expect(httpProviderObj).toBeDefined();
        expect(httpProviderObj.interceptors).toContain('SetCSRFToken');
      });
});
```

In karma conf all needed files are loaded but I'm getting this unknown error:

```
/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4414:53
forEach@/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:24
loadModules@/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4374:12
createInjector@/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4299:22
workFn@/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2427:60
Expected undefined to be defined.
/Users/teone/Sites/xos/views/ngXosLib/xosHelpers/spec/csrftoken.test.js:17:37
```

Any idea?

Comment: I've noticed that if I add a non-existing module in the dependencies list of `xos.helpers` the error remain the same... normally it is something like: `NoMod....`

Comment: I admit I'm not an expert here, but in my tests, I use angular's mock injector: beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(\_SetCSRFToken\_)  ...(something to try at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the issue.

I was not injecting `ngResource` module in `xos.helpers` module. Adding `Chrome` along with `PhantomJs` in karma `browsers` section print out a meaningful error that guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need use inject for get the angular services and providers, try this:

```
describe('The xos.helper module', function(){
      var SetCSRFToken, httpProviderObj;

      beforeEach(module('xos.helpers'));

      //Instead 'module' use 'inject'
      beforeEach(inject(function($httpProvider){
        httpProviderObj = $httpProvider;
      }));

      beforeEach(inject(function(_SetCSRFToken_){
        SetCSRFToken = _SetCSRFToken_;
      }));

      it('should exist', () => {
        expect(SetCSRFToken).toBeDefined();
      });

      it('should set SetCSRFToken interceptor', () => {
        expect(httpProviderObj).toBeDefined();
        expect(httpProviderObj.interceptors).toContain('SetCSRFToken');
      });
});
```

Comment: Already tried... same error... I guess that there is something wrong in the configuration but that error is a bit unclear...